# vb.net botones editables por el usuario final de la aplicacion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms

### Título

Hola comunidad, necesito su ayuda, es posible crear una ventana donde el usuario pueda agregar botones, redimencionarlos, etc. algo como lo que hacemos en visual studio, pero a manera de usuario final donde guarde los cambios y al abrir la ventana se vea como la dejó. Alguna extencion?  vb.net winforms

Comment: que tipo de aplicacion seria? es winform, WPF, etc

Comment: Claro que es posible, pero como bien comenta Leandro, por favor primero indicanos que tecnologia vas a usar lo comun seria que usar winforms o WPF

Comment: winforms, jejeje

Answer (score 0):

Puedes similar la toolbox del Visual Studio

[DockPanel Suite](https://dockpanel2012.codeplex.com/)
[DockPanel Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto tendrias resuelto el tema del diseño de la toolbox.

Ahora poder arrastrar y soltar control en tiempo de diseño es algo mas complejo, pero seguramente tengas que implementar las acciones de Drag and Drop.

[Implementing Drag and Drop in Your Windows Application](http://www.codemag.com/article/0803041)

Comment: gracias lo veré todo :b

Comment: Asu que antiguo ese Visual Studio

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no es el VS, se trata del componente DockPanel. Si el estilo es de un VS algo mas antiguo, pero hay que tener en cuenta que es un componete de libre uso. Si se quiere ir a un diseño mas actualizado se deberia recurrir a componente de pago, como ser DevExpress o Telerik. Trate de recomendar componente free aunque no sean lo mejor en el diseño, imagine no tendria dinero para invertir, y usar componente con licencias ilegales creo que tampoco es la idea recomendar.